# Using filters with keras and OpenCv?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a Q-learning model using Reinforcement Learning to play a simple "Chrome Dino Game". But I got stuck when trying to use an OpenCV function to filter the images effortlessly. This here is my CNN code:

```
class ConvolutionalNeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(input_shape, action_space):   # Removed Self
        model = models.Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(32,
                              8,
                              strides=(4, 4),
                              padding="valid",
                              activation="relu",
                              input_shape=input_shape,
                              data_format="channels_first"))
        model.add(Conv2D(64,
                              4,
                              strides=(2, 2),
                              padding="valid",
                              activation="relu",
                              input_shape=input_shape,
                              data_format="channels_first"))
        model.add(Conv2D(64,
                              3,
                              strides=(1, 1),
                              padding="valid",
                              activation="relu",
                              input_shape=input_shape,
                              data_format="channels_first",))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
        model.add(Dense(action_space))
        model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",
                           optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.00025,
                                             rho=0.95,
                                             epsilon=0.01),
                           metrics=["accuracy"])
        return cur_input
        model.build(input_shape=(80,80))
        model.summary()
```

I had spied this simple function to efficiently preprocess my output to the desired level however am not able to figure out how and where *to connect* them both in the code

```
def process_img(image):
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = image[:300, :500]
    return image
```

For a clear demonstration, I am trying to do something like this (ignore the last set):
[image: Processing the Image for further analysis]

*Note:* I will prefer to use OpenCV if possible but if there is some other alternative which is **FAST** and efficient and can be easily used, I shall accept it

Comment: Preprocessing. Not part of your model.

Comment: @danielMöller what do you mean by that?

Comment: That you preprocess your images "before" feeding them to the model. Shape `(images, size1, size2, 4)`.